# Variadic macros - Comma before the ellipsis?

Tags: c, macros, standards, variadic

I have the following code:

```
#define MACRO(x...) x
MACRO(foo,bar)
```

which, using `gcc -E`, shows that `MACRO` expands to `foo,bar`. However, the C11 standard defines the following syntax for function-like macros:

> ```
> # define identifier lparen identifier-list opt ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
> # define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
> ```

none of which seem to allow the `x...` bit. Oddly enough, the snippet above expands to `foo,bar`, while `#define MACRO(x, ...) x` correctly expands to `foo`. Is this a gcc bug, or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Nevermind, this seems to be a gcc extension, documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Answer (score 1):

GCC has its own rules. A comma before the ellipses means the parameter is required, no comma means it is optional.